How to use a "Session" object?
Is there any way in Delphi to have a session-object that I do not have to pass through every procedure by parameter?
I receive a web-call, I have my internal object that receives all calling data and will also receive results and feedback data. How can all functions that might be used in the course of this web-call add their input without having to pass this object (or a direct reference to it) to every procedure, function or (worst case) property?
A global variable will of course not do, as I may have several calls in parallel.
Every web-call is a separate thread (INDY), is there anything in multi-threading that can help me here?

Objects come with a reference that is available in any methods. Try an Object Pascal book that goes over basic object use.

@Brian Please dont comment if you dont understand the question

You mention the threads are from Indy. If you are using Indy's TIdHTTPServer, you can enable its SessionState property to let each request have its own TIdHTTPSession object associated with it. You can store whatever you want in each session.
But, the sessions are only accessible via the TIdHTTPRequestInfo and TIdHTTPResponseInfo objects, so you are still going to have to pass things around to your existing functions. In which case, you might consider deriving a new class from TIdHTTPSession and make your functions be class methods instead, and then you can use the TIdHTTPServer.OnCreateSession event to create instances of your class, and access those instances in your TIdHTTPServer.OnCommand... events.  This way, your methods can update the calling session as needed.

You may use a threadvar to store some string representation of your internal object state, or use its value as a map key (where the map is a global TObjectDictionary<string, TYourThreadData).

Sometimes, however, you may want to use variables that are global to
all the routines running in your thread, but not shared with other
instances of the same thread class.

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Using_Thread-local_Variables

But then again it could be properties of the own thread class, too, because there should be virtually no chance that OP is not inside his class with any code.

I found the ThreadVars but failed to see the connect with the dictionary. This might actually work! :-)
